# How to get FxCop working with Sonar for a C# solution?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, fxcop, sonarqube

I am currently trying to use FxCop to analyze the assemblies generated by my solution within Sonar and am getting the following message when Sonar calls FxCop to scan each project:

```
INFO  No assembly to check with FxCop
```

Any help with correcting this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the content of your POM or your sonar-project.properties file, you certainly missed some properties or added too many of them.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam I figured this problem out finally.  It was quite simple.  Jenkins is building the project in Release configuration while Sonar is checking for the assemblies in the Debug configuration.  I just changed Jenkins to build the project in Debug mode.

Comment: You also have an option ("sonar.dotnet.buildConfigurations") on the C# Plugins to specify the build configuration to use. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-csharp-core-plugin

Comment: The solution was to make sure that all projects were being built into the location that Sonar was scanning, not a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that all projects were not being built to the same output directory, which was corrected.  All projects must be built in order for FxCop to be able to scan since FxCop scans binary files.

Answer (score 4):

We put some efforts to give sample projects for every language. In your case, you can have a look at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp to compare your configuration and try to find what's missing.