# Default directory layout for Sonar

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube

I prepared Sonar for analizing my C# project. I installed sonar and sonar-runner and also configured the C# plugins (.NET Core, C# Core, FxCop, Gendarme, Gallio, OpenCover and StyleCop)

So far everythings works fine. In Sonar I see my code statistics (LOCs and so on) and I also see the code violations. There is no code coverage buts thats ok because I do not have any tests.

The problem is that I only see violations regarding Stylecop, so it just shows some code style problems. But I am sure that my application also must have other violations that should be detected by FxCop and the other plugins.

In this picture one can just see that it shows a violation from StyleCop. All my violations are ONLY from StyleCop.

[image]

In the [Sonar C# Documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C#+Plugins+Troubleshooting) I have read that it can happen that Analysis succeeds but too few violations were found, maybe because of the wrong assambly direction.
I show you my sonar-runner.properties, maybe here is the cause of my problems:

```
#----- Default Sonar server
#sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
#sonar.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

#----- MySQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
#sonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#----- Oracle
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE
#sonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

#----- Global database settings
#sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default directory layout
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
sonar.binaries=src

#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I also want to list my application structure:

```
-->ProjectMainFolder
   -->Project.sln
   -->sonar-project.properties

   -->Project1Folder
       -->bin
       -->object
       -->Properties
       -->Project1.csproj
       -->Project1Main.cs

   -->Project2Folder
       -->bin
       -->object
       -->Properties
       -->Project2.csproj
       -->Project2Main.cs
```

So the question again:
Why do I only see StyleCop violations and no violation from FxCop, Gendarme and so on?

I also want to add my sonar-project.properties:

```
# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=Project description

# Project identification  
sonar.projectKey=Vendor:Project
sonar.projectVersion= 1.0
sonar.projectName= Project 

# Info required for Sonar  
sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#Core C# Settings  
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=Project.sln
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you should not put project specific settings in the sonar-runner.properties file, you should create a "sonar-project.properties" file inside your solution and keep it there
- Second, in this "sonar-project.properties" file, "sonar.sources" should be set to "." and you shouldn't have "sonar.tests" nor "sonar.binaries"

All this is well explained in the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C#+Ecosystem) and applied in the [sample project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp).

Comment: 1.: I have compiled all my projects in the project folder prior to analysis. 2.: They assamblies does not have been moved they are in the bin/release folder of each project. 3.: The solution folder also have not been moved. Everything is in its original position

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: sonar-runner.properties are just for the global configuration and the project specific configuration is just handled in sonar-project.properties? I also add my sonar-project.properties to see if there is something wrong because I already set the sources to '.'

Comment: Now I tryied the C#-example project you mentioned...there I can see only stylecop and csharpsquid violations but not fxcop and gendarme violations at it is stated in the source code of this example project. Something must be wrong with the settings but I dont know what

Comment: Look carefully into the log and search for "FxCop" or "Gendarme": you should find some hints.

Comment: For FxCop it says multiple times: Skipping the non generated assembly of project : CSharpLib          No assembly to check with FxCop.   But why...I thought the example project of Sonar contains errors that can be checked with FxCop (and also Gendarme)

Comment: Well, it is fairly obvious: "non generated assembly" means that you haven't compiled the project... So my first guess was right.

Comment: But this cant be, I just took the example project from GitHub and in the folder bin/release there already is a CSharpLib.dll. So FxCop has an asambly to read

Comment: No! You have to compile it on your own computer because the Debug files (*.PDB) contain references to local paths. And your path is not the same as mine!

Comment: Thank you Fabrice. I will accept your answer although this is not the real correct answer but you gave me the ideas to find the solution. I rally apprechiate your help

Comment: 404 on the sample project link

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

Fabrice - Sonar Team just brought me to this thought, that FxCop and Gendarme could not work correctly because they have no assambly to work with.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709184/how-to-get-fxcop-working-with-sonar-for-a-c-sharp-solution) I found the soultion. FxCop just searches for assamblies in the Debug folder, and because I just had my assamblies in the release folder it did not work properly. So I changed them back to Debug (or sonar.dotnet.buildConfigurations propery) to solve it